# into_shape after remove_index fails

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

I have an `&[f64]` with 309.760 elements. This dataset is an array of 7040 property sets. Each property set contains a pair of `f64`s and 14 triplets of `f64`.

I am only interested in the triplets.

I can read this dataset into an ndarray like this:

```rust
let array = Array::from_iter(data);
let mut propertysets = vector.into_shape(IxDyn(&[7040, 44])).unwrap();
```

and I can remove the first two `f64` of each property set like this:

```rust
propertysets.remove_index(Axis(1), 0);
propertysets.remove_index(Axis(1), 0);
println!("{:?}", propertysets.shape()); // [7040, 42]
```

which looks promising. But now I want to reshape the array into [7040, 14, 3], which should work because `3 * 14 = 42`, but:

```rust
let result = propertysets.into_shape(IxDyn(&[7040, 14, 3])).unwrap();
```

panics with this message:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ShapeError/IncompatibleLayout: incompatible memory layout'
```

The [documentation of remove_index](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.remove_index) says:

> the elements are not deinitialized or dropped by this, just moved out of view

which probably explains why this fails. But how to do it right? Do I have to copy `propertysets` somehow into a new ndarray of the correct shape? But how?

Using `Array::from_iter(propertysets.iter())` results in an ndarray of `&f64` instead of `f64`.

Comment: Earlier on you have `44` instead of `42`. Is that a typo in the question, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the into_shape operation to work arrays have to be c-contiguous or fortran-contigous in memory (see [docs](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.12.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.into_shape)). After

```
vector.into_shape(IxDyn(&[7040, 44])).unwrap();
```

they are contiguous. But after

```
propertysets.remove_index(Axis(1), 0);
```

they are not. Why? The whole array is not moved with `remove_index`. The elements are just moved out of view (see [docs](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.remove_index)).

**How to solve this?**

1. reassemble using `from_shape_vec`
2. use the new `to_shape` func. (not it the docs yet, but here is some [info](https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray/pull/982) and lots of examples [here](https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray/blob/master/tests/reshape.rs))

Example:

```
use ndarray::{Array, Order, ViewRepr};
use ndarray::IxDyn;
use ndarray::Axis;
use ndarray::ArrayBase;
use ndarray::CowRepr;
use ndarray::Dim;
use ndarray::OwnedRepr;

fn into_shape_reassemble(data: Vec<f64>) -> Array<f64, IxDyn>
{
    let array = Array::from_iter(data);
    let mut result = array.into_shape(IxDyn(&[7040, 44])).unwrap();

    result.remove_index(Axis(1), 0);
    result.remove_index(Axis(1), 0);
    let result = Array::from_shape_vec((7040, 42), result.iter().cloned().collect()).unwrap();

    let result = result.into_shape(IxDyn(&[7040, 14, 3])).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", result.shape());
    result
}
fn to_shape(data: Vec<f64>) -> ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f64>, IxDyn>
{
    let array = Array::from_iter(data);
    let mut result = array.into_shape(IxDyn(&[7040, 44])).unwrap();

    result.remove_index(Axis(1), 0);
    result.remove_index(Axis(1), 0);

    let result = result.to_shape((7040, 14, 3)).unwrap().to_owned();
    println!("{:?}", result.shape());
    result.into_dyn()
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn test_into_shape() {
        let data = vec![0.; 7040 * 44];
        super::into_shape_reassemble(data);
    }
    #[test]
    fn test_to_shape() {
        let data = vec![0.; 7040 * 44];
        super::to_shape(data);

    }

}
```

Output:

```
[7040, 14, 3]
[7040, 14, 3]
```